# Can I get the CartoCSS from a mapbox map?

Tags: mapbox

Say I'm linking to a map made by someone else **kitsunde.foo-bar-foo**, is it possible for me to discover what CartoCSS was involved in rendering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope! CartoCSS is a pre-processor for Mapnik XML styling. When you upload a style to Mapbox from Mapbox Studio Classic, the CartoCSS is converted to Mapnik XML, and by the time it's actually in the browser, it's been combined with the vector sources and rendered into a static image. The CartoCSS is never stored on Mapbox's end.

Comment: Ah cool thanks. Btw you guys really need to document the functions attached to the image-filters, it's not even possible to figure out the argument order of scale-hsla without reading the source to CartoCSS on GitHub. Styling the satellite map which doesn't have distinct layers is an exercise in trial an error using those things it seems.

Comment: I agree! We are working on getting some documentation for image-filters now.